# Authenticating a login - C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication, forms-authentication

Heyo, I'm new to C# MVC and I'm having a problem Authenticating a login. Hopefully you can help.

Using debug mode, it seems that I am able to access the database and collect the correct information to log in, however once I am redirected, the

```
@if (this.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

is skipped and goes to the show login code block when I want it to display Account | logout.
I'm guessing I'm using the wrong code to do this.

Here is my Controller code.

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login([Bind(Include="Email, Password")] User user)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //Get info from database
            var result = from u in db.Users
                         where (u.Email == user.Email && u.Password == user.Password)
                         select u;

            if (result.Count() == 1)
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Email, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Pictures");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid Username and Password combination");
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The Partial View Code

```
@model Project1.Models.Users
<div id="login">
@if (this.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
//***This bit is not validating***
{
@:My Account | Logout 
}
else
{
using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Users"))
{
    <span>
        @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Email)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(u => u.Email)
    </span>

    <span>
        @Html.LabelFor(u => u.Password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(u => u.Password)
    </span>

    <span class="login">
        @Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Users")
        <input class="login" type="submit" name="login" value="Log In" />
    </span>
}
}
```

I'm still learning the basics so please keep it as simple as possible! I'm not too worried about password salts and security I just want to be able to login for now. Once I'm more experienced I will make it more secure.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my knowledge it looks right, but what settings do you have in your webconfig? Mine looks like this in system.web:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies" />
</authentication>
```

Comment: You're absolutely spot on! Thanks a lot =)